# Map-reduce для обработки телеметрии

Tags: архитектура, map-reduce

Можно ли использовать модель map-reduce для хранения и обработки данных телеметрии. 
С точки зрения обработки важна последовательность при анализе показаний. Как с этой проблемой справляются при распараллеливании вычислений? Будет ли от применения модели map-reduce польза?

Интересно чем пользуются для сбора и анализа данных при разработке турбин или самолетов.

Поясню.

Имеем проект по сбору и аналитике телеметрии. На текущий момент данные для анализа хранятся в реляционной СУБД. 
Из плюсов:

- данные в одном месте
- удобно использовать
- большой набор инструментария по анализу (оконные функции SQL, группировки, сортировки)

Что не устраивает:

- ограничения по масштабированию. Отсутствует возможность горизонтального масштабирования БД. Как по размеру хранилища так и по его производительности.
- обеспечение отказоустойчивости. Есть желание настроить распределенное хранилище.

Смотрим в сторону hadoop. Из того что на текущий момент выяснили, основной бонус от использования map-reduce в возможности распаралелить обработку и в "свертываемости" результата. Пока что я не понимаю, как можно организовать reduce-шаг именно на телеметрических данных.

Спасибо.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, **в чём именно вы видите проблему**, как её воспроизвести, **что вы хотите получить в результате** и т. д. **Приведите пример**, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Знаете высказывание Карла Сагана о том. что если хотите сделать яблочный пирог с нуля, сначала придётся изобрести Вселенную? Вот ваш вопрос, приблизительно, спрашивает, вкусный ли получится пирог.

Comment: Я расширил описание проблемы. Скажите этого все еще не достаточно?

Comment: Вам нужно хранить все данные и делать аналитику по всем данными (пакетная обработка) или нужна аналитика по ходу получения данных в пределах некоторого окна (потоковая обработка)? Нужно сохранить данные в "сыром" виде, чтобы потом обрабатывать разными методами или посчитать некоторые метрики, сохранить куда-либо и потом визуализировать?

Comment: Наибольшая часть метрик рассчитывается и отображается постфактум по запросу. При этом используются разные метрики, разные алгоритмы расчета и выбирается произвольный охватываемый интервал времени.
Часть метрик (меньшая) рассчитывается в реальном времени. 
Данные сохранять нужно в сыром виде, т.к. некоторые значения датчиков зависят от настроек и могут на одних и тех же сырых данных давать разный итоговый результат.
Наибольшей проблемой при подготовке предпросчитанных метрик является наличие произвольных рассматриваемых непрерывных интервалов. Ну и +изменяемые настройки.